# Access google cloud windows server via web

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there a way to remote desktop into a Windows VM on google cloud via the web without using RDP.

I am able to connect to the VM via RDP, but would like to connect via a web application or other means.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it personally but VNC should work. You'll have to review and open the necessary firewall ports.

Www.realvnc.com